# Android Serializer causes java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: android, json, kotlin, parsing, permissions

I have an Android project built using Gradle, android 31 that reads a file I placed in assets/ and parses it from json to display it inside a List in a RecyclerView.

The project was working before, then I added some navigation using a ViewPager and suddenly the parsing stopped working. The project originally used Moshi to parse and I switched to Serializer to see if it was the culprit but I keep getting the same error.

My Serializer objects are:

```
    val format = Json {
        isLenient = true
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        coerceInputValues = true
    }
    @Serializable
    data class KBRow(
    @Serializable(with = KBSerializer::class)
        val cells: List<KBCell>? = null
    )

    @Serializable
    data class KBCell(
        val cell_type: String? = null,
        val source: List<String>? = null
    )
    object KBSerializer : JsonTransformingSerializer<List<KBCell>>(ListSerializer(KBCell.serializer())) {
        // If response is not an array, then it is a single object that should be wrapped into the array
        override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement =
            if (element !is JsonArray) JsonArray(listOf(element)) else element
    }
```

Which are then opened using:

```
val sdFile = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(context?.assets?.open(kbFilePath!!)))
if (sdFile != null) {
  val fileContents = format.decodeFromString<KBRow>(sdFile.readText())
  Log.d("project", fileContents.toString())
}
```

I started checking the code and sdFile.readText() works properly and gives me a JSON Stream. But whenever I try to get it as JSON to navigate I get:

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil.createWithTypeRefiner(Unknown Source:0)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.checker.NewKotlinTypeCheckerImpl.<init>(NewKotlinTypeChecker.kt:77)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.checker.NewKotlinTypeCheckerImpl.<init>(NewKotlinTypeChecker.kt:73)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.checker.NewKotlinTypeChecker$Companion.<clinit>(NewKotlinTypeChecker.kt:68)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.checker.NewKotlinTypeChecker.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.DeserializationComponentsForJavaKt.makeLazyJavaPackageFragmentProvider(DeserializationComponentsForJava.kt:171)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.DeserializationComponentsForJavaKt.makeLazyJavaPackageFragmentProvider$default(DeserializationComponentsForJava.kt:146)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.DeserializationComponentsForJava$Companion.createModuleData(DeserializationComponentsForJava.kt:111)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.runtime.components.RuntimeModuleData$Companion.create(RuntimeModuleData.kt:32)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ModuleByClassLoaderKt.getOrCreateModule(moduleByClassLoader.kt:58)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData$2.invoke(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:36)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData$2.invoke(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:35)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data.getModuleData(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:35)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:50)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:48)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.kt:48)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.kt:182)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.kt:44)
        at kotlin.reflect.full.KClassifiers.createType(KClassifiers.kt:48)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl.typeOf(ReflectionFactoryImpl.java:124)
        at kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection.typeOf(Reflection.java:127)
        at KBSFileFragment.onCreateView(KBSFileFragment.kt:198)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1764)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1701)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:488)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:314)
2022-04-22 22:35:40.189 4076-4076/mobile E/AndroidRuntime:     at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:268)
```

I noticed that I can successfully get the data if I use **val fileContents = Json.parseToJsonElement(sdFile.readText())** instead, but then I can't directly get the cells and I find it weird that it started causing that error when it worked well previously.
I investigated and there're posts about configuring a Maven file which I tried on Gradle but don't seem to impact the build and the app keeps crashing whenever I reach the **format.decodeFromString(sdFile.readText())** line and giving the permissions error.

Is this really about permissions or there's something else I'm missing?

Comment: I just tested and it seems to do the same for any external library. Already tried to add exceptions and reconfigure Gradle to avoid signed jars to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to create a new project and test the **implement** libraries in Gradle. It worked in the new project so it seems it wasn't caused by the libraries.

I'm not sure if the fact I ran git from outside Android (in terminal) caused the libraries to be signed too and thus caused errors, but whatever the case sadly I couldn't fix it directly.

Many of the proposed solutions are in maven and suggest adding exclude to signed files, but at least in my case they did nothing.